# SSIS 2008 parsing flat file

Tags: ssis, flat-file

I'm trying to import the following txt file with SSIS 2008.

```
:BEGIN
"2011-12-19 10:30:56"
"Alignement pos.10-74"  -0.0010
"Côté Rouage"
"X_pos.réf.10"  -8.8340 -8.8340 0.0020  0.0020  -0.0000 
"Y_pos.réf.10"  1.0330  1.0330  0.0020  0.0020  -0.0000
```

I defined the ff connection as:
Code page : 1252 ANSI ; format : delimited ; Text qualifier: " ; Header row delimited {CR}{LF}

when I then preview , only 1 column is defined and contains the whole row.
If I add 5 more columns, and skip the 4 first rows, the import works as expected, but if I don't skip rows, the first column will come as: :**BEGIN"2011-12-19 10:30:56""Alignement pos.10-74"**

Any idea how to get correct data from that FF ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I just tested to do the same import with DTS 2000, no problem! Is there any bug with SSIS 2008?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a bug, but generally speaking SSIS is much stricter than DTS in what it accepts, e.g. there are no implicit data type conversions. Personally I would use some custom code (e.g. in a Script Task or Transformation) to parse this file, because it isn't a "simple" CSV format.